# Where is the sqlite database file created by Django?

Tags: python, django, macos, sqlite

I've got python installed and sqlite is included with it... but where is the sqlite db file path that was created with `manage.py syncdb`? I'm on a mac.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In the `settings.py` file, there is a variable called `DATABASES`. It is a dict, and one of its keys is `default`, which maps to another dict. This sub-dict has a key, `NAME`, which has the path of the SQLite database.

This is an example of a project of mine:

```
CURRENT_DIR= '/Users/brandizzi/Documents/software/netunong'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': CURRENT_DIR+ '/database.db', # <- The path
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

You can easily retrieve this value using the Django shell that is accessible running the command `python manage.py shell`. Just follow the steps below:

```
>>> import settings
>>> settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']
'/Users/brandizzi/Documents/software/netunong/database.db'
```

If the returned value is some relative path, just use `os.path.abspath` to find the absolute one:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.abspath(settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'])
'/Users/brandizzi/Documents/software/netunong/database.db'
```

Comment: When you deploy to say a Heroku server, does the database get deployed to that server too?

Comment: This helped me after I moved my `settings.py` file to a `settings` folder to split for different environment settings. My local db file moved one directory inward and it kept creating an empty one. Good to know how this works

Answer (score 0):

if settings not available then this could embedded in your packageName/base Directory:

try:

```
import packageName
import os.path.abspath
 In [3]: os.path.abspath(packageName.DATABASES['default']['NAME'])`
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ca6dcbd75c6d> in <module>()
----> 1 os.path.abspath(settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'])
>>> NameError: name 'settings' is not defined
>>> os.path.abspath(packageName.settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'])`
>>> '/Users/brandizzi/Documents/software/netunong/database.db'
```