# How to use sqlite3 database with Django on Kuberenets pod

Tags: python, django, docker, sqlite, kubernetes

I am having one python-django project which consist of sqlite3 database, I am deploying it on Kubernetes pod, wanted to know how to access the sqlite3 database, once I deploy the app on Kubernetes. Generally If I was using postgres or mysql, I would have created another pod and then expose my services, not sure for sqlite3 database. How to access it and use the database, or I have to create a new pod for sqlite3?

Dockerfile for my Django app:

```
FROM python:3.4

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        sqlite3 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sqlite file should be created in the root of the project inside the pod. But, you should not use sqlite in Kuberneters. Because inside the pods, all the codes are [read-only mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/). Hence even if you want to update the sqlite file, you won't be able to do that unless you give it write permission from dockerfile.

Also, you need to keep in mind, after each deployment pods are recreated, so the sqlite file will be replaced by new one on each deployment and you will lose all your data.

Potential solutions are:

1. You can add [persistant volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) to sqlite file path, so it won't be lost after each deployment.
2. Deploy a MySQL/Postgres DB in kubernetes, and create a Database there. Then connect your Django application to that DB.
3. Even better, use a reliable/paid solution like AWS RDS or Cloud SQL.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Just wanted to know how to add persistent volume to sqlite file path. I know how to create persistent volume, but didn't get how to add persistent volume to sqlite file path

Comment: You mean to say in deployment.yaml file under moutpath in volumes need to give path for the sqlite file?

Comment: you can define the name of the sqlite3 like `/some_directory/sqlite3.db`(where sqlite file is found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431138/where-is-the-sqlite-database-file-created-by-django) and in pods.yml, add `volumeMounts`'s mountPath to `/some_directory`. This document might help: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/. But keep in mind that, persistant volume is not available in Kubernetes build process(unless you explicitly attach it), so you need to run migrations and migrate commands with `CMD` or during running the pod.

Comment: Well, SQLite supports WAL mode to allow concurrent access, so in theory you can create volume or statefulset that contains database files

Comment: Hi @ruddra, can you please clarify what do you mean "...unless you give it write permission from dockerfile." I just can't seem to get it to work in a Kubernetes pod, getting - django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file
 I'd appreciate it very much :)

Comment: @Erokos you need to run chmod command to run the files

Comment: @ruddra, not to spam this post please check out the problem I have and what I have tried so far, described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69703942/using-django-with-db-sqlite3-with-persistent-volume-in-a-kubernetes-pod-outputs?noredirect=1#comment123211935_69703942

Comment: #2 and #3 are pretty useless advices, sqlite works fine in persistent volumes and will cover needs of the most of the projects.

Comment: @Desprit, I believe they are the most useful advice if you consider production grade setup. SQLite is useful only if in prototyping state where you don't have store data for a long time or on permanent based.

Comment: @ruddra This is wrong. For the most of the projects sqlite will be faster than postgres. It's also easier to setup, easier to write unit tests, easier to migrate. Performance in WAL mode is very high. You can even make it distributed using packages like `rqlite`. You underestimate sqlite.

Comment: Its based on project requirements. if its a testing, embedded, or prototype, why not. but for a production grade software, i would think twice: https://dev.to/codesphere/should-i-use-sqlite-postgresql-or-mysql-1o4b